# Run commands on BaseX database

Tags: java, basex

From theoretical point of view how can be run a command for BaseX database in Java (like commands described in http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands). Exist some framework that work to an abstraction level higher than XPath?

Answer (score 2):

BaseX offers a whole bunch of [native language clients that directly connect with BaseX' API](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients).

Using the `QUERY` command boils down to connecting and then querying the database, excerpted from the official query [documentation example](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/tree/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/api):

```
// create session
BaseXClient session = new BaseXClient("localhost", 1984, "admin", "admin");
final String input = "for $i in 1 to 10 return <xml>Text { $i }</xml>";
Query query = session.query(input);
while(query.more()) {
  System.out.println(query.next());
}
```

Other commands have the same kind of interface.

BaseX can also be used im embedded mode from Java, see the ["Local Examples"](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Java_Examples) section of the BaseX documentation.